# R package "infer" - Iterative bootstrapping / looping over column names

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm bootstrapping with the infer package.
The statistic of interest is the mean, example data is given by a tibble with 3 columns and 5 rows. My real tibble has 86 rows and 40 columns. For every column I want to do a bootstrap simulation, like shown below for the column "x" in tibble "test_tibble".

```
library(infer)
library(tidyverse)

test_tibble <- tibble(x = 1:5, y = 6:10, z = 11:15)

# A tibble: 5 x 3
      x     y     z
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     6    11
2     2     7    12
3     3     8    13
4     4     9    14
5     5    10    15

specify(test_tibble, response = x) %>% 
  generate(reps = 100, type = "bootstrap") %>% 
  calculate(stat = "mean") %>% 
  summarise(
    lower_CI = quantile(probs = 0.025, stat),
    upper_CI = quantile(probs = 0.975, stat)
  )
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  lower_CI upper_CI
     <dbl>    <dbl>
1     2.10        4
```

I am now looking for a way of doing the same thing for the other columns in my tibble. I have tried a for-loop like this:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(test_tibble)){

  var_name <- names(test_tibble)[i]

  specify(test_tibble, response = var_name) %>% 
  generate(reps = 100, type = "bootstrap") %>% 
  calculate(stat = "mean") %>% 
  summarise(
    lower_CI = quantile(probs = 0.025, stat),
    upper_CI = quantile(probs = 0.975, stat)
  )
}
```

Unfortunately, this returns the follwing error

```
Error: The response variable `var_name` cannot be found in this dataframe.
```

Is there any way of iterating over the columns x, y and z without entering them manually as arguments for "response"? That'd be quite tedious for 40 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky question with a tricky answer.

Take a look at the `response` argument of the `specify` function in [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/infer/versions/0.5.0/topics/specify):

> The variable name in x that will serve as the response. **This is alternative to using the formula argument.**

With this in mind I modified the code to automate the process, adding one more column to the original dataframe and using the `formula`  argument to obtain the same result, using a column of ones as explanatory variable.

```
library(infer)
library(tidyverse)

test_tibble <- tibble(x = 1:5, y = 6:10, z = 11:15, w = seq(1, 1, length.out = 5))

for (i in 1:ncol(test_tibble)){

  var_name <- names(test_tibble)[i]

  specify(test_tibble, formula = eval(parse(text = paste0(var_name, "~", "w"))))[, 1] %>% 
    generate(reps = 100, type = "bootstrap") %>% 
    calculate(stat = "mean") %>% 
    summarise(
      lower_CI = quantile(probs = 0.025, stat),
      upper_CI = quantile(probs = 0.975, stat)
    )
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That's a very clever solution!
There's just a little mistake in it: the pipe (test_tibble %>%) is superfluous as you entered test_tibble as first parameter into the specify()-function.

Comment: Sorry for that, first I tried to do other thing and I left that code. I edited the answer and now everything is fine